# Searching content of a file

Tags: java, file-io

I dont have alot of experience working with files. I have a file. I have written the following to the file

```
Test 112
help 456
news 456
Friendly 554
```

> fileOUT.write("Test 112\r\n");//this is a example of how I entered the data.

Now I am trying to search in the file for the word news and display all the content that is in that line that contains the word `news`.

This is what I have attempted.

```
if(fileIN.next().contains("news")){
    System.out.println("kkk");
}
```

This does not work. The folowing does find a word news because it displays KKK but I dont have an Idea how to display only the line that it news was found in.

```
while(fileIN.hasNext()){
                    if(fileIN.next().contains("Play")){
                        System.out.println("kkk");

                    }
                }
```

What must be displayed is `news 456`.
Thank You

Comment: How have you defined `fileIN`?

Comment: File users = new File("users.txt");     Scanner fileIN = new Scanner(users);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to call `fileIN.nextLine().contains("news")`

Try using the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class if you are not already. It does a wonderful job of splitting input from a stream by some delineator (in this case the new line character.)

Here's a simple code example:

```
String pathToFile = "data.txt";
String textToSearchFor = "news";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(pathToFile);
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    if(line.contains(textToSearchFor)){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
scanner.close();
```

And here's an advanced code example that does much more than you asked. Enjoy!

```
//Search file for an array of strings. Ignores case if caseSensitive is false.
public void searchFile(String file, boolean caseSensitive, String...textToSearchFor){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        String originalLine = scanner.nextLine();
        String line = originalLine;
        if(!caseSensitive) line = line.toLowerCase();
        for(String searchText : textToSearchFor){
            if(!caseSensitive) searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
            if(line.contains(searchText)){
                System.out.println(originalLine);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    scanner.close();
}

//usage
searchFile("data.txt",true,"news","Test","bob");
searchFile("data.txt",true,new String[]{"test","News"});
```

Comment: Fantastic, I'm glad to have helped! Please accept this answer to close the question. You can accept by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code...:D

```
String s = null;
    File file = new File(path);
    BufferedReader in;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        while (in.ready()) {
            s = in.readLine();
            if(s.contains("news")){
            //print something
            }
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```